# XPath get element by text of previous element

Tags: xml, xpath

I need to get the text of the second element (`Description`) depending on the previous element text.

```
<world>
  <continent>europe</continent>
  <description>germany, france, italy, spain</description>
</world>
<world>
  <continent>asia</continent>
  <description>japan, thailand, china</description>
</world>
<world>
  <continent>africa</continent>
  <description>south africa, simbabwe, tansania</description>
</world>
```

XPath:

```
//world[continent="africa"]/description
```

I tried couple of variations, but nothing is working well.
Any Ideas?

Comment: What price element? Where is it in the XML?

Comment: Oh sorry. Changend the Story while writing.

Comment: Your xml is without root element that do it invalid. After adding it, `/world` will find nothing. You need add one more slash before to make it working `//world[continent="africa"]/description`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This XPath,**

```
//world[continent="africa"]/description/text()
```

**applied to your XML made to be well-formed by adding a wrapper root element,**

```
<r> 
  <world> 
    <continent>europe</continent>  
    <description>germany, france, italy, spain</description> 
  </world>  
  <world> 
    <continent>asia</continent>  
    <description>japan, thailand, china</description> 
  </world>  
  <world> 
    <continent>africa</continent>  
    <description>south africa, simbabwe, tansania</description> 
  </world> 
</r>
```

**will yield**

```
south africa, simbabwe, tansania
```

**as requested.**

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be

```
//world/continent[text()="africa"]/following-sibling::description/text()
```

It means: get `continent` nodes by text content equal to "africa", and from there take next sibling node, which should be a description.

Comment: I think what @MCG asks for is `//world/continent[text()="africa"]/following-sibling::description[1]/text()`, i.e. not select all following siblings, but only the first one.

Comment: I don't think it matters in this case.

Comment: It does work, but it's a bit more complicated than necessary:   `following-sibling::` is **[not necessary](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38133087/290085)**.

Comment: @kjhughes I agree that it can be simpler, didn't think of simpler version you posted.